# Flutter camera plugin terminal output

Tags: flutter, camera

I am working to create a fruits detection app on live feed using Flutter camera plugin https://pub.dev/packages/camera i am facing one issue that camera always give output like bellow in terminal and never stops

I/BufferQueueProducer(13803): SurfaceTexture-0-13803-9 queueBuffer: slot 0 is dropped, handle=0x78a1f90640
I/BufferQueueProducer(13803): SurfaceTexture-0-13803-9 queueBuffer: fps=29.40 dur=1020.32 max=47.33 min=20.83

Comment: are you only trying to capture the image of the subject

Comment: no its is live feed